# itertools.groupby returning wrong result (this is not about sorting)

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator, python-itertools

I wanted to break a string into words, but keeping the index where the word started. E.g., I want to transform `'aaa bbb ccc'` into `[(0, 'aaa'), (4, 'bbb'), (8, 'ccc')]`. *This is just the background, not the question*.

The problem is that I tried to use `itertools.groupby` with `str.isalpha` as key, but it's giving me weird results.

This code shows what I'm talking about (please ignore the `list` everywhere. I just wanted to be sure I was dealing with iterables, not iterators):

```
from itertools import groupby

text = 'aaa bbb ccc'

chars = list(groupby(list(enumerate(text)), lambda x: x[1].isalpha()))

result = [list(v) for k, v in chars if k] 

print result
assert result == [
        [(0, 'a'), (1, 'a'), (2, 'a')],
        [(4, 'b'), (5, 'b'), (6, 'b')],
        [(8, 'c'), (9, 'c'), (10, 'c')]]
```

The variable `result` is ending up as `[[(10, 'c')], [], []]` and I don't know why. Maybe I'm missing something really simple here, but I just can't see it.

Comment: you could do `print` every step to figure out

Comment: This doesn't help much, because the objects created by `itertools.groupby` don't show much info when printed. It would be just a sequence of lines `<itertools._grouper at 0x7f12d72616d0>`.

Comment: don't do `list()` on chars.

Comment: Yes, it was something simple. Please, @LittleQ, write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct the code:

```
chars = groupby(l, lambda x: x[1].isalpha())
result = [list(v) for k, v in chars if k]
```

To figure out the weird output

```
>>> l = list(enumerate(text))

>>> chars = groupby(l, lambda x: x[1].isalpha())

>>> list(chars.next()[1])
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'a'), (2, 'a')]

>>> for k,v in list(chars): print list(v)
[]
[(10, 'c')]
[]
[]
```

`list` would take effect on the sub-iterator in `groupby`